# Using the Google geolocation object as a session var

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I'm building an app which needs to know where the user is; it displays events within a radius of the user.

I'm using the Google geocoding API and have been saving the returned object as a session variable and passing the info to and fro using ajax to retrieve and update the location.

I've noticed that occasionally the array and object keys will be different. For instance, sometimes it will have a nicely formatted `results.geometry.location.lat` hierarchy, but then occasionally it will be `results.geometry.location.d` and sometimes even `results.geometry.location.A`.

I created a getter in javascript which will return the lat and lng regardless of the keys returned. I'm surprised that the returned objects don't have built in getter functions when the array keys vary like that.

So, I'm wondering if there's a better way to store the user's location than just saving the entire geolocation response. I tried paring it down to just what I want to use, but that means every time I make a call to Google for a location, I need to process it.

Has anyone had any experience getting this sort of thing to work?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

I'm using cakePHP and I realized I should have made this a datasource from the get-go. I currently have all the logic in a component being called from my controllers. I'm going to spend some time creating a datasource, which should take care of the getting and setting of this mutating object.

Comment: You should be able to process it every time using various php functions and a bit of clever logic. 

What have you tried?

Being that you will have to request users' permission to locate them, how you decide to structure this app will be very important. 

Research it a bit if you see this being a problem definitely post back, or add to your question.

Comment: *I'm surprised that the returned objects don't have built in getter functions when the array keys vary like that* : no need to be surprised, the getter-functions are `lat()` and `lng()` https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng